# NESTJS EXPRESS-SESSION REDIS: cookie per user

Tags: node.js, session, redis, nestjs, passport.js

I have a NestJs app with PassportJs, Express-Session and Redis as session storage. Actually, I'm trying to implement a remember-me feature and I'm facing a problem and can't see why it's not working. The session created succesfully inside the DB, without any error, except the cookie stored in the DB has cookie.maxAge = null and cookie.expires = null. Any idea ?

app.module.ts

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule{
    
constructor(@InjectConnection(ConnectionName.DB_ALPHA_REDIS_CONNECTION_NAME) private readonly connection: Redis) {}
      configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
          .apply(
            session({
              name: process.env.ALPHA_AUTH_SESSION,
              store: new RedisStore({ client: this.connection }),
              saveUninitialized: false,
              secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
              rolling: false,
              resave: false,
              cookie:{ httpOnly: true, secure: false, sameSite: true }
            }),
            passport.initialize(),
            passport.session(),
          )
          .forRoutes('*');
      }  
    }
```

local-auth.guard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local'){

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext){
       
        const REQUEST = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
        const RESPONSE = context.switchToHttp().getResponse()

        const BODY = plainToClass(LoginBody, REQUEST.body)

        const ERRORS = await validate(BODY)

        const ERR_MESSAGES = ERRORS.flatMap(({ constraints }) =>
            Object.values(constraints),
        );

        if(ERR_MESSAGES.length > 0)
            RESPONSE.status(404).send(buildResponse(404, 'There is some errors', ERR_MESSAGES))

        REQUEST.sessionStore.ttl = BODY.rememberMe ? 60 * 60 : 60
        REQUEST.session.cookie.maxAge = BODY.rememberMe ? 60 * 60 * 1000 : 60 * 1000

        // return 3600 as expected
        console.log( REQUEST.sessionStore.ttl) 

        /**
        return as expected
        cookie: {
          path: '/',
          _expires: 2023-06-20T00:24:26.712Z,
          originalMaxAge: 3600000,
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: false,
          sameSite: true
        }
        Inside redis cookie.originalMaxAge = null
        cookie.expires = null 
        */
        console.log( REQUEST.session.cookie)

        const RESULT = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean
        
        await super.logIn(REQUEST)
        return RESULT
    }

}
```

Inside redis DB:

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":false,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/","sameSite":true},"passport":{"user":{"id":"648a59999f34ed94915ed3ba"}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a possible solution is to use REQUEST.session.save() in LocalAuthGuard's canActivate method to ensure that the session is saved correctly after changing maxAge and ttl. You can try the following changes:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local'){

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext){
       
        const REQUEST = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
        const RESPONSE = context.switchToHttp().getResponse()

        const BODY = plainToClass(LoginBody, REQUEST.body)

        const ERRORS = await validate(BODY)

        const ERR_MESSAGES = ERRORS.flatMap(({ constraints }) =>
            Object.values(constraints),
        );

        if(ERR_MESSAGES.length > 0)
            RESPONSE.status(404).send(buildResponse(404, 'There are some errors', ERR_MESSAGES))

        REQUEST.sessionStore.ttl = BODY.rememberMe ? 60 * 60 : 60
        REQUEST.session.cookie.maxAge = BODY.rememberMe ? 60 * 60 * 1000 : 60 * 1000

        // Save the session after modifying ttl and maxAge
        REQUEST.session.save(err => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        });

        // return 3600 as expected
        console.log( REQUEST.sessionStore.ttl) 

        /**
        return as expected
        cookie: {
          path: '/',
',
          _expires: 2023-06-20T00:24:26.712Z,
          originalMaxAge: 3600000,
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: false,
          sameSite: true
        }
        */
        console.log( REQUEST.session.cookie)

        const RESULT = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean
        
        await super.logIn(REQUEST)
        return RESULT
    }

}
```

another solution, try setting maxAge and ttl after calling super.logIn(REQUEST). :

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local'){

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext){
       
        const REQUEST = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
        const RESPONSE = context.switchToHttp().getResponse()

        const BODY = plainToClass(LoginBody, REQUEST.body)

        const ERRORS = await validate(BODY)

        const ERR_MESSAGES = ERRORS.flatMap(({ constraints }) =>
            Object.values(constraints),
        );

        if(ERR_MESSAGES.length > 0)
            RESPONSE.status(404).send(buildResponse(404, 'There is some errors', ERR_MESSAGES))

        const RESULT = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean
        
        await super.logIn(REQUEST)

        REQUEST.sessionStore.ttl = BODY.rememberMe ? 60 * 60 : 60
        REQUEST.session.cookie.maxAge = BODY.rememberMe ? 60 * 60 * 1000 : 60 * 1000

        // Save the session after modifying ttl and maxAge
        REQUEST.session.save(err => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        });

        // return 3600 as expected
        console.log( REQUEST.sessionStore.ttl) 

        /**
        return as expected
        cookie: {
          path: '/',
          _expires: 2023-06-20T00:24:26.712Z,
          originalMaxAge: 3600000,
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: false,
          sameSite: true
        }
        */
        console.log( REQUEST.session.cookie)

        return RESULT
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already tried this solution but unfortunately, didnt work. Weird, maybe something wrong with the express-session or connect redis

Comment: @Mlouden，try setting maxAge and ttl after calling super.logIn(REQUEST).

Comment: My friend hats off, you'r a legend !. So the logIn function overrides the data before inserting into DB. Good to know Thank you for your help, appreciate !